# HTML checkbox and meteorJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mongodb, meteor

I do not fully understand this code in the meteorJS TODO tutorial:

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" checkbox="{{checked}}" class="toggle-checked" />
```

Javascript:

```
"click .toggle-checked": function(){
  Tasks.update(this._id, {
    $set: {checked: ! this.checked}
  });
```

so program is listening to the click event at `class:toggle-checked`, and update mongoDB with `$set` operator to create a property "checked" with value **not** equal to "checked" property of HTML input class: `toggle-checked`.

Why not equal?

Comment: The HTML looks not good. Also the JavaScript doesn't seem complete. Can you please [edit] it to make better? See the preview while editing at the bottom.

Comment: Sorry - its my first time using stackoverflow.

Comment: No problem. Can you please [edit] and make it better?

Answer (score 0):

Since the `checked` field in the db holds a boolean value, when the checkbox is rendered it uses the `checked` value as its state. When the checkbox state changes, so should the `checked` field as well.

Let's apply this logic with a very basic example:

```
Action        this.checked value    Initial checkbox state      Updated checked value
===========================================================================================

None          false                 not-checked                 false (no action triggered)
Click         true                  checked                     true
Click         false                 not-checked                 false
```

Answer (score 0):

> update mongoDB with $set operator to create a property "checked" with value not equal to "checked" property of HTML input class: toggle-checked

From your above statement, it seems to me that you got confused by `this.checked`. In the event handler, `this` actually refers to the current template's data context and therefore, `this.checked` is not the checked property value of the HTML element.

So, when a task is not checked, the value in its checked field will be false. Since, `this` is referring to this data context, `this.checked` is also false. But when you click on the `.toggle-checked` checkbox, you want to set the value of the checked field to true. Therefore, we set the value of checked field to `! this.checked`. We are not using the checked value of the HTML element to update the checked state in this example.